# ArrayList Processing - How to access each index separately

Tags: arraylist, processing

As it is a first time I'm using ArrayList in Processing I'm experiencing some issues.

I have created an Arraylist that stores a PVector (x,y position) of an Ellipsee.

What I'm trying to do is very simple I think but I can't find much info on ArrayLists.

Code:
    ArrayList position;

```
void setup() 
{
   position= new ArrayList<Vectors>();
}

void draw() 
{
   position.get(i).display(); //display ellipse
}

void mousePressed() 
{
   position.add(new Vectors(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY)));
}
```

So every time mouse is Pressed a new ellipse is created at mouseX mouseY position. What I would like to do is when my I created an amount ellipses, I need to control each one separately to change it's size or color either by clicking on them or with KeyPressed().

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't compile automatically as I'm assuming your PVector object has already been created and that it has two public attributes of xPosition and yPosition:

```
// Initialise your arraylist
ArrayList<PVector> listOfPVectors = new ArrayList<PVector>;

// Objects can be added to your list as follows:
PVector pvectorObject = new PVector();  
listOfPVectors.add(pvectorObject);

// The size of your ArrayList can be output as follows:
println(listOfPVectors.size());

// You can iterate through every entry in the arraylist as follows:
for(int index = 0; index < listOfPVectors.size(); index ++) {
    println("X Position Value = " + listOfPVectors.get(index).xPosition);
    println("Y Position Value = " + listOfPVectors.get(index).yPosition);
}
```

Basically, you use the ArrayList.get(indexPosition) method to retrieve any element you want from your ArrayList. You can then work away with it as normal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Anthony thank you for your answer. Does the getXPosition() work in Processing?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer to suit Processing a bit more clearly. Hopefully it's a bit clearer now (I removed the getter methods for getXPosition() and getYPosition()). Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Thank you Anthony it does help me. However I think to print the values in processing is: println("Y Position Value = " + listOfPVectors.get(index).x);

Comment: It depends on what you called those attributes in the PVector object. In my assumption above, I have called them xPosition and yPosition but if you have used simple x and y variables for these, then that's fine, too. Use those instead.

Comment: Thank you Anthony. I manage to do it. Just one question if you can help me. I manage resize the ellipse on mousePressed using position.get(i).display(r*2);. However when the mouse  is released it goes back to normal. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How are you drawing the ellipse?